# Routing priority confuse about Express

Tags: express

All:

I am pretty new to Express.js, say if I specify Routes like:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
app.get('/hello', function(req, res){res.send("hello");});
```

inside index.js, I set routing like:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This seems both handle same url request, I wonder how does Express decide which handler to use?

Thanks

Comment: When you use app.get('/hello',___), it means you are setting the middleware which will run before any request made to '/hello'. so first app.get will be use and print "hello" & router.get will never call as app.get end the response with "hello" text.

Comment: @rroxysam Thanks, however when I tested it, I do not know why it went into router.get()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All middlewares and routes in express are stacked and executed top down.

```
router.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send('This get executed');
});
router.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send('This will NOT get executed since you are ending the response with res.send in the route above');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so when it comes to my case, which one get first executed and why?

Comment: Layman's rule - Which ever you see on your editor first, gets executed.

Comment: Thanks,  so the handler inside app.use("/", __)  gets first.