# Express restful routes pathing issue

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm having an issue with my Rest service. The two routes I'm trying to have are:

```
 router.get('/stocks/:ticker', function(req, res){
```

and

```
router.get('/stocks/watchlist/', function(req, res){
```

when I call

```
http://localhost:8000/stocks/watchlist
```

my API believes 'watchlist' is the ticker symbol and goes to the incorrect route.  I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Did you try to change the order? Express will use the first route to match the pattern.

Comment: It would be  better to change the route `/stocks/:ticker` to something else  like `/stocks/heartbeat/:params`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing priority confuse about Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299927/routing-priority-confuse-about-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the watchlist route in front of the other one.

That way it will get matched before the more open ended one gets to see the request at all.  Routes are compared in the order they were defined and the first one to match gets it first.  If it doesn't call `next()` to continue routing, then it will be the only one to see the route.